# Are GUID across Object Stores in FileNet CE 5.2 unique?

Tags: guid, filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine

I have a requirement wherein I need to search for Documents using only GUID across Object Stores. 
1. Is it possible that GUID is duplicate across Object Store ? 
2. In such a case where GUID is duplicate, how do I retrieve the Document Content ?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the GUID is always unique, but at least when working on the API you will have a separate object store connection for each object store, then you would not have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is it possible that `GUID` is duplicate across Object Stores ?

As the name says, global unique identifier (`GUID`) is unique. Here the scope 'global' is limited to an Object Store. So, Yes. When you are dealing with multiple object stores, it is possible that you encounter the situation where objects having same `GUID` but belong to different object stores. However, this situation is highly unlikely if you let FileNet to generate the `GUID` for you as FileNet generates the `Id` randomly.

In v5.2.1, a new algorithm is used to generate the `Id` monotonically having mixed time and counter based portions with a random portion. I believe this would completely elemenate the odds of having same `Id` occurrence for the objects from different object stores.

However, if you use FileNet Deployment Manager for migration, it lets you keep the same Id for the objects that you are migrating.

2. In such a case where `GUID` is duplicate, how do I retrieve the Document Content ?

This would only happen when your search scope involves multiple object stores and your SQL with where clause `"Id={....}"` returns a `DocumentSet` containing 2 instances(if you are using `MergeMode.UNION`). If you know from which object store you want the document from, you'll know which instance's content you want to retrieve.

If your search scope involves only one object store then you'll find only one `Document` instance for the `GUID` given.

Answer (score 1):

Classes have guids (Id), and FileNet provided **classes** like "Document" or "Custom Object" will have a guid that is exactly the same across Object Stores.

Instances of classes (objects), also have guids (Id).
Document objects (instances of class Document) will (almost) always be unique (Id, whereas they are Versionable objects, and thus contain a "Version Series" guid as well).

If you were to deploy a Document object from one Object Store, to another, using FileNet Deployment Manager, then you could keep the id guid the same, resulting in the same guid, across two different Object Stores.  This is the only case where you will end up with two Document Objects with the same Object_Id... by purposely doing so.

FileNet has many ways to return a document.
You can use SQL syntax and return a document object using the guid doing something like "Select * from Document where Id = 'guid'"
You can also do something like

```
"Document doc = Factory.Document.fetchInstance (ObjectStore, Id, PropertyFilter)"
```

In the second case you would need to already know what ObjectStore the record is contained in.

Chances are, if you are able to find the Id of a record, you should probably know the ObjectStore anyway.

Comment: I believe, GUID depend on the Domain. I have multiple Object Stores under same domain. FileNet Object have same GUIDs and also other Object would have unique IDs.